# PHP JS - Codigo repetindo os artigos

Tags: javascript

Porque e que o meu script continua a receber os artigos apos ter feito todo o loading de scroll? Quero que ele pare quando acaba...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var limit = 6;
  var start = 3;
  var action = 'inactive';

  function load_country_data(limit, start) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "inc/class_home_store.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        limit: limit,
        start: start
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#load_data').append(data);
        if (data == '') {
          $('#load_data_message').html("<button type='button' class='btn btn-info'>No Data Found</button>");
          action = 'active';
        } else {
          $('#load_data_message').html("<span><b>Carregando</b>...</span>");
          action = "inactive";
        }
      }
    });
  }

  if (action == 'inactive') {
    action = 'active';
    load_country_data(limit, start);
  }
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#load_data").height() && action == 'inactive') {
      action = 'active';
      start = start + limit;
      setTimeout(function() {
        load_country_data(limit, start);
      }, 1000);
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Provavelmente esse `setTimeout` está mal implementado. Se vc fizer dois scrolls (ou mais) seguidos, vai gerar um gargalo de setTimeout e a variável `start` não vai sincronizar com esse tempo.

Comment: o que recomenda fazer?

Comment: @Sam o que recomenda que faça...

Comment: Tente retirando esse setTimeout deixando apenas `load_country_data(limit, start);`